# PlayOnLinux install menu incomplete display

Tags: display, playonlinux

As you can see, this install menu is not complete, the border is cut and I can't maximize the windows. What can I do?

[image]
[image]

Comment: have you tried grabbing the corners with the mouse and dragging it to larger size?

Comment: The mouse doesn't change it's icon as it should be when you point to the border, so...it can't

Comment: Hey, I just upgraded PlayOnLinux from 4.2.4 to 4.3.4 and they fixed this bug, now this windows can be resized.

Comment: Glad it got fixed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just upgraded PlayOnLinux from 4.2.4 to 4.3.4 and they fixed this bug, now this windows can be resized.